# How to Mock a constructor using Mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a class like this:

```
public class A {

public Integer callMethod(){
  return someMethod();
}


private Integer someMethod(){
  //Some Code
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(oAuthMessage.URL);
  //Some Code
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); ------1
  Integer code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); ---2
  return code;
}
```

Now I want to mock the line 1 & 2 & return a mock HttpResponse & code.

I have tried this but failed:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {

//Spying some things here & Injecting them

@Test
public void testA() {

   HttpResponse httpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
   HttpClient httpClient = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
   HttpPost httpPost = Mockito.mock(HttpPost.class);

   Mockito.doReturn(httpResponse).when(httpClient).execute(httpPost);
   Mockito.when(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).thenReturn(anyInt());
   //call the method
}
```

But this is not working. Can anyone give me any idea please?
Thanks.

Comment: [Powemock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) is the way to go

Comment: Alternatively, understand your problem is more that you are creating **untestable** code. Yes, Powermock can help with that; but the better approach is to well, write more testable code. See here for what means: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79

Comment: To actually answer why it is not working: It doesn't matter if you mock the `HttpClient` because right before the line you marked with `1` you create a "new" `HttpClient`.

The object needs to exist on class level in order for you to inject it.